# Release PORT 53 | Mesos-DNS on Marathon

Tags: ubuntu, mesos

I am trying to setup a Apache mesos cluster with mesos-dns to resolve names.

I could setup the cluster as well, but I am having trouble to run mesos-dns on marathon.

I followed [this tutorial](http://frankhinek.com/setup-mesos-multi-node-cluster-on-ubuntu/) for the cluster, and [this other one](https://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/docs/) for mesos-dns.

**My problem is:**

When I try to mesos-dns on marathon, I get an error saying that

> ERROR: 2015/10/27 17:08:41 main.go:80: Failed to setup "tcp" server: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:53: bind: address already in use

I've ran

> netstat -tupln

and got this result:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Endereço Local          Endereço Remoto         Estado       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.56.102:5051     0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    OUÇA       -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53712           0.0.0.0:*                          -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60978           0.0.0.0:*                          -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                          -               
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                          -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23667           0.0.0.0:*                          -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          -               
udp6       0      0 :::51616                :::*                               -               
udp6       0      0 :::53326                :::*                               -               
udp6       0      0 :::19587                :::*                               -               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                               -
```

which says that the system is listening on port 53. There is no PID for this process; so, how can I kill this and release the port?

Answer (score 1):

Killed using:

```
sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:53`
```

Comment: Do you actually need to use `sudo` twice in the same line ?

Answer (score 0):

## Free Port 53

```
sudo lsof -t -i :53 | xargs sudo kill -9
```